# "Action for ultimate recipient is required", unable to consume SOAP service

Tags: .net, web-services, soap, wse

I have a SOAP web service I am trying to test but am unable to get anything to work. I do have access to the service's code, have tried calling from SoapUI, VS's service reference, and rolling my own XML, all to no avail.

No matter what I do I am receiving this error:

> Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.SecurityFault: Header http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing:Action for ultimate recipient is required but not present in the message.

Here is the relevant code for trying to use the Visual Studio generated Service Reference (which is pointing to a .asmx). As you can see, nothing interesting going on...
Console app:

```
Magi.ServiceSoapClient client = new Magi.ServiceSoapClient();

string magiVersion = "1.2";
string returnXml = string.Empty;

client.Open();
try
{
   client.CheckPricing(magiVersion, ref returnXml);
}
catch (Exception) { }

Console.Write(returnXml);
Console.Read();

client.Close();
```

VS generated code in Reference.cs

```
// CODEGEN: Generating message contract since the wrapper namespace (http://www.company.com/product/2) of message CheckPricingRequest does not match the default value (http://www.company.com/product/2/ws/)
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://www.company.com/product/2/ws/wsdl/Service.wsdl", ReplyAction="*")]
magi_ws_tester.Magi.CheckPricingResponse CheckPricing(magi_ws_tester.Magi.CheckPricingRequest request);
```

I have tried attaching a Header any way I could find, and trying messing around with SoapUI's WS-A functionality, but have been unable to get past this issue.

To note: navigating to the .asmx or asmx?WSDL in a browser works perfectly, VS and SoapUI capture the details and methods of the service as expected.

Comment: That service is using the obsolete and unsupported tool called "WSE". It also happens to be non-standard in some areas (it was released before the standards were finalized). If at all possible, that service should be upgraded to WCF, not because it's newer, but because WSE is unsupported.